# Will enclosing main application object in try-catch block catch all crashes?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception

If I enclose the main application object in try-catch block, will it catch any unforeseen crashes? Will the control come here in the event if the application was to crash because of any reason?

The following is an example using Qt application but assume this application is very large, loads other dlls etc but still this would be the main body of application. So will guarding this block, guard everything in that application effectively?

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QTextEdit>

    int main(int argv, char **args)
    {
        int exit_code = 0;

        try
         {
             QApplication app(argv, args);

             QTextEdit textEdit;
             textEdit.show();

            exit_code = app.exec();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            // will this catch all crashes?
        }

        return exit_code;
    }
```

Technically exceptions handlers obviously catch any exceptions thrown within that block but I am wondering how does this scale to enclosing the whole app in a catch block.

Also I know it will probably not do anything useful since we wouldn't know what exception has been thrown/caught but I am wondering if I can use this to catch a mysterious and random crash? Will it catch for example access violation 0xc0000005 excpetion?

Comment: Exception handling doesn't catch *any* crashes. It only handles exceptions.

Comment: `Will it catch for example access violation 0xc0000005 excpetion?` No.

Comment: You have to catch the signal from the Operating System and handle it. If your program is being slapped down by the OS in this way, the program is broken and very likely already corrupted beyond repair. Trying to continue is foolhardy.

Comment: The thing you can use to catch this mysterious crash is a debugger. They're quite good at it.

Comment: @deviantfan Actually on Windows it will.

Comment: @immibis, You might be thinking of `__try` and `__except`.

Comment: @immibis `__try` and `__except` are MS-specific things which have nothing to do with standard C++ `try` / `catch`

Comment: @deviantfan Last I checked, `catch(...)` caught SEH exceptions (such as access violations) as well as C++ exceptions. I never mentioned `__try` and `__except`.

Comment: @immibis That's interesting... I have to try that too...

Comment: @immibis `Last I checked, catch(...) caught SEH exceptions` That depends on the compiler and compilation options. For MSVC that would be the [`/EHa` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx) and [_set_se_translator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5.aspx), for example.

Comment: @KerrekSB the intent is the same like any other try-catch block and whatever it catches. On Windows most errors if not all like memory access violation I believe does through `AfxThrowUserException` after displaying crash dialog.

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you post this answer and if you can also speak to if it will catch all normal exceptions deeply nested in the exe like in a dll called by this exe? I will accept that as answer.

Comment: I don't really have anything to add. Whether exceptions propagate through DLLs is probably a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you could still crash.

The `try-catch` block will only catch exceptions that are thrown via the `throw` keyword.
If you access outside of memory, or divide by zero for example, your program may or may not crash.

Additionally, `try-catches` can not stop `abort()` from terminating the program.

Your `access violation` is likely a segmentation fault.  You will need to prevent the problem from ever occurring.

Comment: It also doesn't catch exceptions thrown from the constructors and destructors of non-local static variables.